# Magento 2 library without composer?

Tags: magento2

What would be the steps and the proper way to call a 3rd party module that you cannot load via composer? Is there a acceptable method for doing this in Magento 2?

I am looking at implementing a 3rd party library into a store but the library is not open source or available on packagist.org.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different possibilities to work with composer package even if they are not in public repository like packagist.

1) Possibility

**Own Composer Repository**, you can achieve this with *[Satis](https://github.com/composer/satis)* or *[Private Packagist](https://packagist.com/)* or *[Toran Proxy](https://toranproxy.com/)*.

2) Possibility

**Artifact**, In this case you don't need have a online repository. Is a compressed folder with your private packages. E.g:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "path/to/directory/with/zips/"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "private-vendor-one/core": "15.6.2",
        "private-vendor-two/connectivity": "*",
    }
}
```

3) Possibility

**Path** You can specify a path (relative or absolute) of your composer repo in host. E.g:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "../../packages/my-package"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "private-vendor/package": "*"
    }
}
```

With these possibilities you don't need deal with others solutions IMHO.

You have more info about composer repos [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am aware of private repositories. However, the usage rights to the library expressly prohibit the posting of the code to 3rd parties including private repositories.

Comment: I missed your comment about an artifact, I'll test this seems like it will suit my needs. Thank you

Comment: You can try with @Rafael solution or with Path or Artifact, maybe is the better approach for you. If you feel comfartable with  solution please upvote the answer :)

Comment: Artifacts where the way to go. I appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Will this automatically integrate library if the composer.json is placed at module's root without composer update command during module installation?

Answer (score 1):

This solution allows you to work with your private repositories at **GitHub** and **BitBucket**.

The branch used is the master, if you want to use the develop for example use dev-develop instead of dev-master.

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/my-private-repo": "dev-master"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url":  "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/my-private-repo.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

> The only requirement is the installation of SSH keys for a git client.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am aware of private repositories. However, the usage rights to the library expressly prohibit posting of the code to 3rd parties including private repositories. I believe what I am going to end up doing is setting the server path to a /lib folder inside my module and then using the directoryList model to retrieve it.